# Can't delete Azure Web Sites Web Hosting Plans

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to delete a Web Hosting Plan on the new azure portal. But when I click on the delete link, I see this message: "Failed to delete web hosting plan Default2: Storage usage quota exceeded. Cannot update or delete a server farm."

There are no websites linked to this web hosting plan. If I try to change the web hosting plan for 'shared', I get this message: "Storage usage quota exceeded. Cannot update or delete a server farm."

This is a standard web hosting plan, I'm paying for this, and I need to delete it.

Someone knows how to delete it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to upgrade your plan,
company can change existing plan to new plan,
you not need to delete,

Answer (score 0):

You maybe receiving the error message below if you created a Logic APP or used the Legacy API:

> "Failed to delete web hosting plan : Storage usage quota exceeded. Cannot update or delete a server farm."

These resources create hidden artefacts that can persist then prevent the App Service Plan from being deleted.

This PowerShell script can help you locate any related resources to the app service plan:

```
$appserviceplan = Get-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name <App Service Plan Name>
$apps = Get-AzureRmWebApp
foreach ($app in $apps) {
if ($app.ServerFarmId = $appserviceplan.Id) 
{$app.Name}}
```

It will return a list of all apps / resource hosted on the App Service Plan named.

The following can then be used to delete the resources:

```
Remove-AzureRmWebApp -Name <App Name>
```